# Massive problems using Three20 with Xcode 4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, three20

I'm trying to install the "Three20" library into an Xcode 4.1 project.

I downloaded what appears to be the latest version (1.0.7) and I ran the python script. No errors generated by the script, but when I start my project, there are no Three20 subprojects listed in the dependencies.

I tried manually added them to the dependencies, but that didn't work either. The compiler complains that dependencies are missing, even though they are there.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you execute the python command with this at the end.

> --xcode-version=4

If that doesn't work try creating a new project and call it "test" (all lower case), and try installing on that. I found deleting a project and creating another with the same name would mess it up, or anything with "Three20" in the name.

btw Where did you get 1.0.7 from? I installed Three20 last week and its at 1.0.6.2.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the python script just doesn't work. I had to manually drag the dependent projects into my project in order to get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me using this script

```
python three20_latest/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p Sample/Sample.xcodeproj Three20 --xcode-    version=4
```